# Django is using wrong TIME_ZONE

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

On my production environment only, my app uses `America/Chicago` as time zone while I have `TIME_ZONE = "UTC"` in my settings.
I'm running my code on Debian and the system locale is `C.UTF-8` with Django 4.1.

I dug in Django code and find the source of my problem here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2118d72d61746f2462fca695dbf3adf44ebf8f7/django/utils/timezone.py#L72

I tried in `./manage.py shell` to reproduce the problem:

```bash
# ./manage.py shell
Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 21 2022, 08:51:48) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> import zoneinfo
>>> settings.TIME_ZONE
'UTC'
>>> timezone.get_current_timezone()
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Chicago')
```

And if I call the methods in `get_current_timezone`, I have a different result

```bash
>>> settings.USE_DEPRECATED_PYTZ
False
>>> zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')
```

Where could the `America/Chicago` come from ?

Comment: Seems like it is cached *before* you enter this. Does your `settings` file imports `django.utils.timezone` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willem was right, I used `timezone.something()` in my settings before the `TIME_ZONE` was set.

For posterity: I'm using `django-split-settings` and was using globs (`"settings/*.py"`) and the order of the files was different locally and in production.